# Is there any way to see recently unplugged devices?

Tags: 20.04, hardware, notification, log

I heard an unplugging notification sound on my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop but actually I didn't unplug anything.I doubt if there is a problem about hardware slots. Is there any file that holds log records to see recently plugged/unplugged devices? Or is there any way to see them?

Comment: Try `dmesg`: Look at the bottom for the most recent messages.

Comment: Yes,this code works for my problem too.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the logs with something like

```
sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"
```

for various values of "5".

Read `man journalctl`.